# JS (function(){}) syntax

Tags: jquery, javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why would one write global code inside a function definition-call pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897987/why-would-one-write-global-code-inside-a-function-definition-call-pair)
>   [How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639180/how-does-the-function-construct-work-and-why-do-people-use-it)

I'm no JS ninja, and I'm now trying to learn the ins and outs of a language that has a lot more depth than I thought!

I've seen a lot of code recently (jquery among them) that's coded like this:

```
(function(){
var myLibrary = .....;
window.myLibrary = myLibrary;
})();
```

Can someone explain to me the benefit of this syntax?  What's the difference between that and just writing something like:

```
var myLibrary = {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 I'd like to know this also.

Comment: Same as [
How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639180/how-does-the-function-construct-work-and-why-do-people-use-it).

Comment: hmmm wonder why those didn't show up in the search before post.  Thanks, feel free to delete!